# Can't ssh so how to install patch 1533 5344?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, patches

My hosting told me can not ssh, so how to install patch 1533 5344?
thank you!!!!!!!

i upload the patch into my root directory and added a php :

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

But :

```
Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed:
Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them).
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option can be to not use patch at all and just upload all patched files from http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!so just upload the file into my root directory is ok?

Answer (score 1):

When the tool "patch" is not installed, you can of course ask your hoster to install this for you. However, in the end, I would say that is dangerous.

Instead, you could copy all files from your Magento installation to your local computer, apply the patch there, and copy the files back. Ideally, you would have a VCS (Version Control System) like git, so that you can modify changes offline and bring them online in a more controlled way.

Comment: You mean hosting help me install it , is  danger?
Installed to update my computer very review, there are other ways?

Comment: Yeah, well, dangerous: If you don't have full control via SSH, then - if things go wrong - you don't have a good way to fix that. I'm not saying that things will go wrong. I'm just saying that we should be extremely careful, when there is no SSH available, and when the hoster also did not have the patch-command preinstalled.

Comment: have some one give me this page:
http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

i gone to this page download the file upload to my root directory is ok?